Ubuntu 24.04 Not Mounting USB Storage on Zenbook Pro 14 Duo (UX8402)
When I plug in USB storage devices, I can see that they are plugged in via the CLI, but they are not mounted or treated like mountable devices by the OS. I've tried with both USBs and external drives.
The drives are also fully functional. Have other computers here and they operate normally in Windows and Linux.
I can see the device with lsusb
$sudo lsusb  

Bus 004 Device 003: ID 05dc:a83a Lexar Media, Inc. USB Flash Drive

There also seems to be no errors related to the device
$ sudo dmesg | tail
[  914.772545] workqueue: pm_runtime_work hogged CPU for >10000us 16 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND
[  993.378927] i915 0000:00:02.0: Using 39-bit DMA addresses
[ 1275.372588] /dev/usb/hiddev0: Can't lookup blockdev
[ 1459.049675] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 1463.347791] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 1463.366816] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05dc, idProduct=a83a, bcdDevice=11.00
[ 1463.366845] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1463.366848] usb 4-1: Product: USB Flash Drive
[ 1463.366851] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Lexar
[ 1463.366854] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: AXXX8UXXXXXXXX

It is not recognized as a block device since I can't see it with lsblk or fdisk -l
$ sudo lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0  55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2823
loop1         7:1    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop2         7:2    0  74.2M  1 loop /snap/core22/1380
loop3         7:3    0 269.6M  1 loop /snap/firefox/4173
loop4         7:4    0  10.7M  1 loop /snap/firmware-updater/127
loop5         7:5    0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198
loop6         7:6    0 505.1M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/176
loop7         7:7    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop8         7:8    0  10.3M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/1124
loop9         7:9    0  38.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21465
loop10        7:10   0   476K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/157
loop11        7:11   0  10.4M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/1134
loop12        7:12   0  85.8M  1 loop /snap/teams-for-linux/583
loop13        7:13   0  85.8M  1 loop /snap/teams-for-linux/584
loop14        7:14   0 137.3M  1 loop /snap/thunderbird/470
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 390.6G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   900M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0   261M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0   100G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
│                                     /
├─nvme0n1p7 259:7    0   398G  0 part /home
└─nvme0n1p8 259:8    0  63.8G  0 part 

I've been having several other issues with this PC in regards to Ubuntu including earlier versions, such as no sound
I haven't been able to mount the devices manually, for example by finding an external HDD via sudo mount /dev/sdb1 ... since it isn't recognized as storage.
